# Cordova Game Center plugin with matchmaking?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, game-center

I'm building a multiplayer mobile game with Ionic (Angular/Cordova), and I'm hoping to be able to integrate Game Center into the app. I've found a couple of plugins, such as [this one](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-game-center/), but the problem with these existing plugins is they don't have support for match making – one of the main features of Game Center.

Can match making be done with Cordova? Or will I need to build a native (non hybrid) app instead with Obj C/Swift? I'm mostly looking for a reason as to why everyone seems to avoid match making when it comes to Game Center used with Cordova.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I can't seem to find a single instance of someone using Game Center's match making feature in a JS/Cordova hybrid app. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure writing a native app is great, but I don't know Swift or Objective C, so if I could build something in just JS with Cordova, that would be ideal. Especially since I've already built an entire prototype using Cordova/Ionic.

Comment: I created this plugins for gamecenter matchs https://github.com/jcesarmobile/GameCenterMatchPlugin, but right now it's for realtime matchs only

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you @jcesarmobile! This should be very helpful with getting me on track.